# Strange behaviour of ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I simply want to draw multiple arrows on a scatterplot using ggplot2. In this (dummy) example, an arrow is drawn but it moves as i is incremented and only one arrow is drawn. Why does that happen?

```
library(ggplot2)
a <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
b <- data.frame(x1=c(2,3),y1=c(10,10),x2=c(3,4),y2=c(15,15))
for (i in 1:nrow(b)) {
        a <- a + geom_segment(arrow=arrow(), 
          mapping = aes(x=b[i,1],y=b[i,2],xend=b[i,3],yend=b[i,4]))
         plot(a)
 }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't strange behavior, this is exactly how `aes()` is supposed to work. It delays evaluation of the parameters until the plotting actually runs. This is problematic if you include expressions to variable outside your data.frame (like `i`) and functions (like `[,]`). These are only evaulated when you actually "draw" the plot.

If you want to force evaulation of your parameters, you can use `aes_`. This will work for you

```
for (i in 1:nrow(b)) {
  a <- a + geom_segment(arrow=arrow(), 
    mapping = aes_(x=b[i,1],y=b[i,2],xend=b[i,3],yend=b[i,4]))
 }
plot(a)
```

Now within the loop the parameters for `x=` and `y=`, etc are evaluated in the environment and their value are "frozen" in the layer.

Of course, it would be better not to build layers in loops and just procide a proper data object as pointed out in @eipi10's answer.

Comment: I think I've heard of the function aes_ before but I couldn't understand it then. Now I get a primer and will check it more. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As @Roland explains in the comment thread to this answer, only one arrow is plotted, because `geom_segment(arrow=arrow(), mapping = aes(x=b[i,1],y=b[i,2],xend=b[i,3],yend=b[i,4]))` is evaluated only when `a` is plotted. But `i` only has one value each time `a` is plotted. During the first time through the loop, `i=1` and during the second time `i=2`. After the loop `i` also still equals 2. Thus, only one arrow is plotted each time. If, after the loop, you run `i=1:2` then you'll get both arrows. On the other hand, if you change `i` to anything other than 1 and/or 2, you won't get any arrows plotted.

In any case, you can get both arrows without a loop as follows:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_segment(data=b, arrow=arrow(), aes(x=x1,y=y1,xend=x2,yend=y2))
```

**Question regarding @Roland's first comment:** Shouldn't the object `a` be updated each time through the loop by adding the new geom_segment? For example, if I start with the OP's original `a`, then after one iteration of the loop,

```
a = a + geom_segment(arrow=arrow(), aes(x=b[1,1],y=b[1,2],xend=b[1,3],yend=b[1,4]))
```

Then, after two iterations of the loop,

```
a = a + geom_segment(arrow=arrow(), aes(x=b[1,1],y=b[1,2],xend=b[1,3],yend=b[1,4])) + 
        geom_segment(arrow=arrow(), aes(x=b[2,1],y=b[2,2],xend=b[2,3],yend=b[2,4]))
```

where in each case `a` means the value of `a` before the start of the loop. Shouldn't those underlying changes to the object `a` occur regardless of the when or if `a` is evaluated?

Comment: Because evaluation happens during plotting and after the loop i == 2.

Comment: @Roland, I have a question regarding your comment, but I've added it to my answer so the code will be easier to read.

Comment: Look at the internals of the ggplot2 object. x = b[i, 1] and it is only evaluated during plotting.

Comment: Does it work that way because the `b` data frame was never passed into the `ggplot` environment using the `data` argument, but is instead drawn from the external environment each time?

Comment: Again, the parameters of aes are only evaluated during plotting. It's only important which value i happens to be then.

Comment: Interesting. So if after the loop, you change `i` to anything other than 1 or 2, then evaluate `a`, you don't get any arrows. On the other hand, if after the loop you run `i = 1:2`, and then evaluate `a`, you get both arrows. Well, I learned something new. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks eipi10 and Roland. I could check draw multiple arrows in my script which is more complicated. I tried it without a loop but I seem to have forgot to provide "data=b". Anyway I also learned something new, thank you.