# Update a ggplot using a for loop (R)

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I am having some problems updating a ggplot object. What I want to do is to put a vertical line in a specific location that I change on every loop, hence: multiple lines will be displayed in different locations. However, when I use a for loop it only shows me the last line that it's created but when I do it manually it works. I created a reproductible example that you guys can check:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)) +
  geom_line()

for(i in 1:6){
  x <- x + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = i*5))
}

y <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)) +
  geom_line()

y <- y + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 5))
y <- y + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 10))
y <- y + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 15))
y <- y + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 20))
y <- y + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 25))
y <- y + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 30))
```

Check both plots. Why is the first plot not looking the same as the second one, although for me both processes do the "same" thing?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39057372/496488) for an explanation of what's happening.

Comment: Using `aes_` instead of `aes` in the `geom_vline` for-loop will give you the same plot as y.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was looking at some contributions that some people left me and there is one who solves it pretty efficiently and it is to use aes_() instead of aes(). The difference is that aes_() forces to evaluate and update the plot, while aes() only evaluates the indexes when the plot is drawn. Hence: it never updates while it is inside a for loop.

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100)) +
  geom_line()

for(i in 1:6){
  x <- x + geom_vline(aes_(xintercept = i*5))
}
```

Comment: This is a very simple solution to the problem with lazy evaluation in looping.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with how ggplot does lazy evaluation -- see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235825/for-loop-only-adds-the-final-ggplot-layer).

Since `geom_vline` is vectorized, this works:

```
library(ggplot2)

x <- ggplot() +
  geom_line(mapping = aes(x = 1:100, y = 1:100))

x + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = seq(5,30,5)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Alex. Actually, your example works in this reproductible example but it is quite limited in other applications. I was just reading some other comments that people let me and the best solution is to use aes_() instead of aes().