# Incorrect colour gradient when using cowplot to patch together plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, cowplot

Say I have a data set with `x` and `y` values that are grouped according to two variables: `grp` is `a`, `b`, or `c`, while `subgrp` is `E`, `F`, or `G`.

- `a` has `y` values in [0, 1]
- `b` has `y` values in [10, 11]
- `c` has `y` values in [100, 101].

I'd like to plot `y` against `x` with the colour of the point defined by `y` for all `grp` and `subgrp` combinations. Since each `grp` has very different `y` values, I can't just use `facet_grid` alone, as the colour scales would be useless. So, I plot each `grp` with its own scale then patch them together with `plot_grid` from `cowplot`. I also want to use a three-point gradient specified by `scale_colour_gradient2`. My code looks like this:

```r
# Set RNG seed
set.seed(42)

# Toy data frame
df <- data.frame(x = runif(270), y = runif(270) + rep(c(0, 10, 100), each = 90),
                 grp = rep(letters[1:3], each = 90), subgrp = rep(LETTERS[4:6], 90))

head(df)
#>           x         y grp subgrp
#> 1 0.9148060 0.1362958   a      D
#> 2 0.9370754 0.7853494   a      E
#> 3 0.2861395 0.4533034   a      F
#> 4 0.8304476 0.1357424   a      D
#> 5 0.6417455 0.8852210   a      E
#> 6 0.5190959 0.3367135   a      F

# Load libraries
library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Plotting list
g_list <- list()

# Loop through groups 'grp'
for(i in levels(df$grp)){
  # Subset the data
  df_subset <- df %>% filter(grp == i)
  
  # Calculate the midpoint
  mp <- mean(df_subset$y)
  
  # Print midpoint
  message("Midpoint: ", mp)
  
  g <- ggplot(df_subset) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y))
  g <- g + facet_grid(. ~ subgrp) + ggtitle(i)
  g <- g + scale_colour_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "yellow", midpoint = mp)
  g_list[[i]] <- g
}
#> Midpoint: 0.460748857570191
#> Midpoint: 10.4696476330981
#> Midpoint: 100.471083269571

plot_grid(plotlist = g_list, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

In this code, I specify the midpoint of the colour gradient as the mean of `y` for each `grp`. I print this and verify that it is correct. It is.

**My question: why are my colour scales incorrect for the first two plots?**

It appears the same range is applied to each `grp` despite subsetting the data. If I replace `for(i in levels(df$grp)){` with `for(i in levels(df$grp)[1]){`, the colour scale is correct for the single plot that is produced.

---

### Update

Okay, this is weird. Inserting `ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]]$colour` immediately before `g_list[[i]] <- g` solves the problem. *But, why?*

[image]

Comment: This commonly comes up with looping and ggplot2.  I'm not sure in your exact case, but it likely this has something to do with when variables are evaluated in the plot.  See the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39057372/2461552) and info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26235825/for-loop-only-adds-the-final-ggplot-layer)

Comment: @aosmith That's really interesting. So, presumably `ggplot_build(g)$data[[1]]$colour` forces evaluation and thus retains the colours as they should be? It seems an alternative is to `print` the plots invisibly: `invisible(print(g))` just before `g_list[[i]] <- g`.

Comment: That's my guess.  One of the things I like about the approach of splitting the dataset into a list by groups and then looping through the datasets to make many **ggplot2** plots with `lapply()`/`purrr::map()` is that it avoids some of this.

Comment: @aosmith Good stuff. I'll try that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: i had a similar case with looping and ggplot, the answer was, ggplot has problems with local variables. I think it's kinda the same here. Still not exactly sure why ggplot behaves like this. [my old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54808795/how-to-add-multiple-curves-functions-to-one-ggplot-through-looping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, you're creating unevaluated promises and then evaluate them at a time when the original data is gone. This problem is generally avoided if you use proper functional programming style rather than procedural code. I.e., define a function that does the work and then use an apply function for the loop.

```r
set.seed(42)

# Toy data frame
df <- data.frame(x = runif(270), y = runif(270) + rep(c(0, 10, 100), each = 90),
                 grp = rep(letters[1:3], each = 90), subgrp = rep(LETTERS[4:6], 90))

library(cowplot)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Loop through groups 'grp'
g_list <- lapply(
  levels(df$grp), 
  function(i) {
    # Subset the data
    df_subset <- df %>% filter(grp == i)

    # Calculate the midpoint
    mp <- mean(df_subset$y)

    # Print midpoint
    message("Midpoint: ", mp)

    g <- ggplot(df_subset) + geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y, colour = y))
    g <- g + facet_grid(. ~ subgrp) + ggtitle(i)
    g <- g + scale_colour_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "yellow", midpoint = mp)
    g
  }
)
#> Midpoint: 0.460748857570191
#> Midpoint: 10.4696476330981
#> Midpoint: 100.471083269571

plot_grid(plotlist = g_list, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Consider `by`, more streamlined than the nested `lapply` + `split` or `lapply` + `levels` or `lapply` + `unique`.